# SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 11 Invalid character length: 2,097,088,000. Must be between 1 and 16,777,216 in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have source column as VARCHAR in teradata with size 2097088000 , what should be the target datatype in Snowflake.
As I can not insert more than 16,777,216 bytes/Chars data which as less 16mb Uncompressed data.

Please help with this .

create or replace table uuu (
ty varchar(2097088000) );

Comment: Snowflake data types support max 16MB for string/text data, see [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html). 2GB is way above that!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)